# Как передать в функцию параметры из объекта?

Tags: php

Всем привет, я только начинаю изучать ООП и столкнулся вот с такой проблемой.

```
<?php 
class Boss {

public $name;
public $lvl;
public $hp;
public $damage;
public $revardPay;
public $revardExp;
public $db;

public function __construct($name, $lvl, $hp, $damage, $revardPay, $revardExp, $db) {

$this->name = $name;
$this->lvl = $lvl;
$this->hp = $hp;
$this->damage = $damage;
$this->revardPay = $revardPay;
$this->revardExp = $revardExp;
}

public function EngineBoss ($name, $lvl, $hp, $damage, $revardPay, $revardExp, $db){    

$LS = new LoginSystem();
$LS->init();

$detailsPay = $LS->getUser('pay'); // Деньги
$detailsExP = $LS->getUser('expirience'); // Опыт
$detailsManna = $LS->getUser('manna'); // Энергия
$detailsPower = $LS->getUser('power'); // Сила
$detailsSutenerHP = $LS->getUser($db); // Здоровье босса
$detailsLvL = $LS->getUser('lvl'); // Уровень
$detailsUmenieGold = $LS->getUser('umenieGold'); // Прибавка к баксам
$detailsUmenieExp = $LS->getUser('umenieExp'); // Прибавка к опыту
$detailsUmenieENG = $LS->getUser('umenieENG'); // Прибавка к энегрии

$pay     = $detailsPay;        // Деньги
$exp     = $detailsExP;        // Опыт
$power   = $detailsPower;      // Сила
$bossHP  = $detailsSutenerHP;  // Здоровье босса
$manna   = $detailsManna;      // Манна
$lvl     = $detailsLvL;        // Уровень
$prem    = $detailsUmenieGold; // Прибавка к баксам
$premExp = $detailsUmenieExp;  // Прибавка к опыту
$umENG   = $detailsUmenieENG;  // Прибавка к энергии

$mannaBoss = $damage;    // Цена энергии за удар
$sumEndPay = $revardPay; // Награда за победу, баксы
$sumEndExp = $revardExp; // Награда за победу, опыт
$endHP     = $hp;        // Возвращаем здоровье боссу после победы

return $mannaBoss;

}
}

 $gopnik = new Boss('Гопник', 15, 10000, 200, 10000, 4000, 'sutenerHp');

 echo $gopnik->EngineBoss(//сюда нужно как-то передать $gopnik);
?>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Постарайтесь пояснее объяснить в чем именно проблема.

Comment: Почему `EngineBoss` не наследует от `Boss`?  https://coder-booster.ru/learning/php-beginners/parent-classes-inheritance

Comment: вот с такой проблемой ! это какой ? вы предлагаете всем пробовать запускать ваш код ? или может поясните все же какая проблема ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так ва не надо ничего туда передавать. Во первых уберите все аргументы из метода `EngineBoss`, они задаются через конструктор класса при создании объекта. А во вторых зачем вам передавать объект в метод который и вызывает этот объект?

Comment: Я до этого так и делал, но return $mannaBoss; не выводит значение, хотя должно вывести 200

Comment: Все я решил проблему нужно было так:  $mannaBoss = $this->damage; а не так:  $mannaBoss = $damage;